# Beamer and newenvironments

Tags: beamer, environments

I'm trying to combine beamer overlays and newenvironments:

```
\newcounter{scount}
\setcounter{scount}{0}
\newenvironment{sitem}[1]
   {%before
   \def\data{#1}
   \stepcounter{scount}
   \onslide<\value{scount}->{\item \data}
   \comment
   }{
   \endcomment
   }
```

and:

```
\begin{itemize}
  \begin{sitem}{data}asdf1\end{sitem}
  \begin{sitem}{data}asdf2\end{sitem}
  \begin{sitem}{data}asdf3\end{sitem}
\end{itemize}
```

But beamer seems to ignore the \onslide command and shows all data values at once instead of data for asdf1, asdf2, asdf3 after each other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps a better way to achieve what you want is as follows:

```
\begin{itemize}[<+->]
\item Foo
\item Bar
\end{itemize}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is the cause of the unexpected behavior, but you can eliminate the extra counter with incremental overlay specifications.

```
\newenvironment{sitem}[1]
   {%before
     \item<+-> #1
     \comment
   }{
     \endcomment
   }
```